# Android: JUnit + Mockito, test callback?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have an `Android` app that I'm working on and trying to write unit tests for it. The app is written with the MVP architecture and I am trying to test the Presenter-class.

Simplified method I'm trying to test looks like this:

```
public void userPressedButton() {
    service.loadData(new Callback<Data>{
        @Override
        onResponse(Data data) {
            view.showData(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I want to verify that when the `userPressedButton` method is called `view.showData(data)` is called.

I have tried several approaches but I can't seem to figure out how to test this.

Any ideas?

Edit: to clarify, I want to write a unit test

Comment: just to be sure.. you want to write a unit test? not an intergration test

Comment: Maciej Kowalski yes that is correct!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Interesting case.

What i would do is to:

**1)** - Create a concrete class for that particular Callback:

```
public class MyCallback implements Callback<Data>{

    private View view;

    public MyCallback(View view){
        this.view = view;
    } 

    @Override
    onResponse(Data data) {
        view.showData(data);
    }
}
```

Now for this class you can write a unit test which would check whether the `onResponse` method calls the `showData` method of the `view` field.

**2)** Having extacted the implementation to a concrete class, from the perspective of the class which contains the `userPressedButton` method, it really is not essential what happens inside of the Callback class.
It is important that a concrete implementation of that interface has been passed:

```
public void userPressedButton() {
    service.loadData(new MyCallback(view));
}
```

and finally the test:

```
@InjectMocks
MyClass myClass;

@Mock
Service service;

@Captor
ArgumentCaptor argCaptor;

@Before
public void init(){
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void shouldUseMyCallback(){
     // Arrange

     // set up myClass for test

     // Act
     myClass.userPressedButton();

    Mockito.verify(service).loadData(argCaptor.capture());

    // Assert
    assertTrue(argCaptor.getValue instance of MyCallback);
}
```

So we check whether the `loadData` method has been called with proper implementation.

Thats how i would test your case.

Answer (score 1):

You could "store" the callback and use a test callback during your test

```
class YourClass {

    private ??? view;
    private Callback<Data> callback;

    // for testing purposes
    protected YouClass(Callback<Data> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public YouClass() {
        this(new Callback<Data>{
            @Override
            onResponse(Data data) {
                view.showData(data);
            }
        });
    }

    public void userPressedButton() {
        service.loadData(this.callback);
    }
}
```

then use some custom callback for your test

Answer (score 1):

Even more simple solution. If this is MVP, you can pass `view` instance to presenter class. Then test invocation on `Mock`.

This is what a test method would look like:

```
MVPView view = mock(MVPView.class);
Presenter presenter = new Presenter(view)
presenter.userPressedButton();
verify(view, atLeastOnce()).showData(any(Data.class));
```

If the call is asynchronious, then wait for the result, by modifying the last statement:

```
verify(view, timetout(5000).atLeastOnce()).showData(any(Data.class));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Does this work even if the loadData method makes a network call?

Comment: Then you have to mock `service` behaviour, too.